# HTTP Error Wordpress on IIS uploading image

Tags: uploads

I have searched high and low for an answer and spent over 4 hours on this seemingly easy problem.  I've tried at least 10 different answers on the web and nothing.  I am trying to upload my first picture into the new Wordpress site I am starting.  upon Upload I get an "http error"  and that's all.  This is so frustrating.  I'm stunned that WP can't bring back a more expressive error so it can be diagnosed and not just continue trial and error for hours.
WP 4.8.2
php 7
iis 6
windows 2008 r2

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you've already tried.   Will save everyone spending time giving suggestions which you've already tried.

Comment: there is a debug mode with a log that you can activate. look this page : https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know people would jump that quick.  I just wanted to get my answer out there in proper format for anyone else trying to figure this out. Let me know if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

I was finally offered a link to use the browser uploader.  I tried that and got a descriptive error message, approximately this:  "Php could not get permission to temporary folder UNKNOWN".  Now that's something I can work with.  I went to php.ini and found sys_temp_dir which says it will default to the standard temporary directory.  So it was not set in my php.ini.  I set it to a specific folder for php that I created g:\phptemp and restarted IIS.  Immediately no problems. Had Wordpress brought back that error message at 8am this morning I would have saved 4 hours poking and proding and trying and failing.  Super frustrating but I'm glad I found the answer and could share it because I NEVER found this answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00696/0/Increasing-maximum-allowed-size-for-uploads-on-IIS7.html

Set your memory to 200MB or something to test and then reboot the machine.   Try wordpress uploads after that.

Comment: Already did that. Along with everything here: [https://themeskills.com/fix-http-error-when-uploading-images-to-wordpress/](https://themeskills.com/fix-http-error-when-uploading-images-to-wordpress/)  and a few others